# How can you cast from T to IObservable<T>?

Tags: c#, mvvm, dto

I'm working with DTOs and MVVM, for me it means that sometimes I need to transform types between DTOs to ViewModels. In this opportunity I'm stuck with trying to convert T to IObservable < T >.

```
StockModel stockModel;
StockViewModel stockViewModel;

stockViewModel.Stock = stockModel;

public class StockViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    IObservable<StockModel> stockModel = null;

    public IObservable<StockModel> Stock { get => stockModel;
        set
        {
            stockModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Stock");
        }
    }
}

public class StockModel:ModelBase
{
    int productID = 0;
    double quantity = 0;

    public int ProductID { get => productID; set => productID = value; }

    public double Quantity { get => quantity; set => quantity = value; }

}
```

The error I get is -

> "Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'StockModel' to 'System.IObservable < StockModel >'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Any ideas how should I proceed?

Comment: I don't see a class called `Stock` in your question. Do you have this class and does it actually implement `IObservable`?

Comment: Stock is a property of the StockViewModel class.

Comment: I saw that, but your error message says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Stock' " .. so that's a type, not a property name.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo when I copied the code into the question format. Just fixed that.

Comment: OK, then the error message is fairly self-explanatory. Your property `Stock` expects an object of type `IObservable<StockModel>`, but you are attempting to set the value using an object of type `StockModel`. These are two different things. The documentation for `IObservable<T>` is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iobservable-1?view=netframework-4.8.

Comment: Would you expect to be able to cast a `public class Tiger` to an `public class Airbus`? `IObservable<StockModel>` is a completely different type than `StockModel`. It doesn't matter that you see "StockModel" in both instances.

Comment: @KennethK.I don't agree. Tiger and Airbus are completely different things. IObservable<StockModel> represents a stream of StockModel values, it can even be a single value as in my current answer.

Comment: @MistyK Well then you don't agree with the C# language.

Comment: @KennethK.what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `stockViewModel.Stock = Observable.Return(stockModel);`

Observable represents a stream of values, in this particular case your stream will always be a single value